# Codeigniter Email Attachment: mail is sent without attachment

Tags: php, codeigniter, email-attachments

I am in a little bit of trouble sending mail with attachments in CodeIgniter. Here is my code:

```
        $to="mailtouser@gmail.com"
        $fileUrl=array(base_url()."assets/pdf/sample.pdf", base_url()."assets/pdf/sample1.pdf");
        $subject="TEST MAIL";
        $message="TEST MESSAGE";
        $this->load->library('email');
        $from = "admin@gmail.com;
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['mailtype']='html';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['priority'] = '2';
        $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
        $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from($from, 'Little Bloom');
        //$this->email->to();
        if($cc!=''){
            $this->email->cc('sendmail@gmail.com');    
        }
        $this->email->bcc($to);

        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        if(!empty($fileUrl))
        {
            foreach($fileUrl as $key)
            {  
                $this->email->attach($key);
            }
        }
        return $this->email->send();
```

There are multiple pdf files so I am using an array to save the URL but when I send this to my email function these files are not attached to the mail.

Comment: What exactly is the content of `$fileUrl`? Run `var_export($fileUrl);` please, so we can see. We need a [mre] of your issue, and that includes any relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

if you print you array $fileUrl, you'll se at once where the problem is. Using e.g.: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($fileUrl);die;`

the urls are missing a forward slash between your_site and assets: `http://your_siteassets/pdf/sample.pdf`

you can fix this either with:

```
$fileUrl=array(base_url("assets/pdf/sample.pdf"), base_url("assets/pdf/sample1.pdf"));
```

or with

```
$fileUrl= array(base_url()."/assets/pdf/sample.pdf", base_url()."/assets/pdf/sample1.pdf");
```

docs url helper [base_url()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url)